# Is "it is" optional in this kind of construction?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, phrase-usage

I wrote this sentence:

> The longer you go without water, the more satisfying (it is) to drink
> it.

Is it is optional here? Why or why not?

Comment: This sort of construction is possible in English, but your sentence is not a good example. It sounds very awkward without “it is” but also a bit awkward with “it is”.  The construction works much better when each correlated phrase is worded simply.  For example, “The greater the thirst, the sweeter the water.” “The bigger they are, the harder they fall.”

Comment: Necessary. Dont know why. i would understand without, but it would be poetic and odd. Not wrong, poetic and odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds a little odd without "it is". The problem with "is it optional" is, as Al pointed out, it sounds kind of poetic when the articles are dropped.

> The longer the lack of water, the more satisfying the drink

This sentence is a modified version that is rather poetic but sounds kind of strange in real conversation.

I'm struggling to understand the context in which you would say this sentence, so I can't give great options, but including "it is" sounds more natural.

Orbital's suggestion of a more poetic expression like "the greater the thirst, the sweeter the water" is definitely also good.